# TCP Connection Block my WPF Window? How to Get WPF Window?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I developing one Application, while developing I get one problem. so I want to resolve it. I'm using TCP Server and Client Concept. I write code well. But Block my WPF Window. How can i resolve it? Can anyone help me.

**My Code**

```
private void LoadingInboxMessage(){
try {
  InboxTCPServer("127.0.0.1",1001);
  string []header = new string[]{"Name","Mobile","Address"};
  SQL sql = new SQL();
  MySqlConnection con = sql.ConnectServer("127.0.0.1","root","''","smsdb");
  if(con!=null) {
    MySqlDataReader dr = sql.SQLFetching(con,"SELECT * FROM receivedetails");
    CreateFlowDocument cfd = new CreateFlowDocument("inboxFlow");
    this.InboxFlowDocument.Document = cfd.CreateTable("inboxtable",header,dr);
 }
     else {
    MessageBox.Show("Not Connectioned");
    Application.Current.Shutdown(0);
 }
} catch(Exception e) {
   MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
     }
}

public void InboxTCPServer(string ipv4, int port){
try {
  IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(ipv4);
  TcpListener serv = new TcpListener(ip,port);
  serv.Start();
  Socket s = serv.AcceptSocket();
  byte[] b = new byte[1000];
  int k = s.Receive(b);
  MessageBox.Show(b.ToString());
} catch(Exception e) {
    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
}
}
```

Please "Help me"

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look to the C# async TCP/IP management. I think your problem is that you hang up your code waiting for a connection in the same thread that is rendering the UI, causing a non-responsive program.
Here you are a couple of link with examples:

- [Asynchronous Client Socket Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a.aspx)
- [Asynchronous Server Socket Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx)

Comment: How have you implemented it in your code?

An other simple solution might be to change from:
 `InboxTCPServer("127.0.0.1",1001);`
to:
`Thread t = new Thread( InboxTCPServer("127.0.0.1",1001));
    t.Start();`